# Other WaveNet voices for Google Assistant

Tags: text-to-speech, actions-on-google

I would like to know if WaveNet voices can be used as an assistant
voice in google actions (Develop> Invocation> Google Assistant voice). For example it-IT-Wavenet-B.
I used a google action that uses these types of voices.

I am waiting for an answer.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

For each locale that your Action supports, you should be able to select the voice from a dropdown. These are going to be the high-quality voices, often or always Wavenet-based. In this screenshot you see the voices for en-US.

[image: Google Assistant voice dropdown]

Comment: So @nick-felker, you confirm that those are the only voices available? I, for Italian, I can only select 2.
But in a Google Action I heard another voice (it-IT-Wavenet-B). Do you think it uses mp3 files inside the ssml markup?

Comment: I couldn't speculate how a particular action is implemented.